# How to retrieve the middle value of a node

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase structure like this

```
"lists" : {
  "-LlBpKy9Q8UfCXCweM4b" : {
    "-LlBy-5Q9HX0YLFkBkev" : {
      "6416739414706" : {
        "addedDate" : "12-8-2019 at: 20:45:38",
        "amount" : 1,
        "contentSize" : 100,
        "objectProducer" : "Nailman",
        "objectType" : "Nails",
        "unit" : "Pcs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to retrieve the objectID ( 6416739414706 ) I retrieve all other values like this:

```
ref?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
    // print(child.value)
    guard let dict = child.value as? [String: AnyObject] else { return }
    self.objectProducer.append(dict["objectProducer"] as! String)
    self.objectType.append(dict["objectType"] as! String)
    self.contentSize.append(dict["contentSize"] as! Double)
    self.objectMeasureUnit.append(dict["unit"] as! String)
    self.objectAmount.append(dict["amount"] as! Double)
    self.objectLastAdded.append(dict["addedDate"] as! String)     
}
```

This works fine, but I have not been able to retrieve the objectID. How can this be done?

Comment: Perhaps `let objectID = child.key`

Comment: @vacawama Easy. Thanks

Comment: @vacawama Feel like posting it as an answer, so that the it can be accepted?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, I posted it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`DataSnapshot` class](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot) has a `value` property which you are retrieving and assigning to `dict` and a [`key` property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot#key) which in your case holds the `objectID` you are looking for.

So to get the `objectID` `String`:

```
let objectID = child.key
```